# Reliable supplier of Ultrafire batteries

Tags: flashlights

I would love to buy one of those great Ultrafire torches and some spare batteries.

[image: Ultrafire Torch]

However I have heard a lot of people online talking about the huge number of counterfeits that sell on eBay, etc.

There are so many companies claiming to supply Ultrafire torches and batteries, but none of them state they are counterfeit, even though some of them surely are. How can I determine which suppliers are offering genuine products?

Comment: I don't know if there even is such a thing as "genuine" when it comes to Ultrafire.  I would not trust any Ultrafire batteries, and there are much better alternatives that are not expensive.  Also if you want a C8 style flashlight look at a Convoy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping-assistance and not about the actual outdoor-related product. It is opinion-based and if reasonable, this belongs to another site in the SE network.

Answer (score 4):

The UltraFire product is manufactured by WhaFat Technological Company, which is based in Hong Kong. Their products look very similar to [SureFire flashlights](http://www.surefire.com/illumination/flashlights.html), so it's possible that UltraFires themselves are clones/knockoffs.

That said, the [WhaFat website](http://www.ultrafire.net/shownews.asp?id=60) recommends purchasing from an official dealer, but they don't mention any. [ultrafire-shop.net](http://www.ultrafire-shop.net) claims to be an official reseller and even has a list of fake websites to avoid, so that might be a good starting point.

I recommend using a website you trust (like Amazon.com) that has a reasonable return policy that would allow you to send back the torch if you don't like it. Look for products with a lot of reviews (several hundred or thousand) and high marks. I would be weary of products with poor or few reviews.

Good luck!